# Отправка отчётов об ошибках на сервер

Tags: android, обработка-ошибок

Какой краш-репортер лучше всего использовать в андроид, для отправки отчётов об ошибках на сервер? Насколько я знаю, есть несколько вариантов: *Crashlytics от Fabric*, *ACRA*, или интеграция *Google Analytics*. А какой вариант из этих (или, возможно, какой-то другой) лучший? Понимаю, что на данный вопрос наверное нельзя дать однозначный ответ, но была бы благодарна за сравнительный анализ (преимущества/недостатки)...

Comment: Crashlytics теперь часть Firebase Error reporting (после покупки гуглом). По простоте интеграции Crashlytics лидирует, а если надо ловить в нативном (С/С++) коде - остальные не помогут.

Comment: @DeKaNszn оформите в виде ответа - комменты обычно теряются, а ответы есть ответы

Comment: @Barmaley развернул комментарий в ответ

Comment: Нашла ещё такую статью по этой теме: https://primesoftpro.ru/blog/mobilnost/avtomatizatsiya_sbora_oshibok_i_sboev_android_prilozheniy/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Crashlytics**
Плюсы:

1. простота интеграции
2. куплен Google и интегрируется в Firebase Error Reporting вместо имевшегося там компонента
3. умеет ловить исключения в C/C++ коде (требуется доп.настройка)

Минусы:

1. Логи и все данные хранятся не у вас (для некоторых критично)

**ACRA**
Плюсы:

1. большой выбор [бекендов](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/Backends)
2. OpenSource

Минусы:

1. Бесплатный бекенд надо разворачивать самостоятельно

**Google Analytics**
Не предназначена для отправки полноценных отчетов, больше для отправки факта "возникла ошибка"

Comment: Ну вот. Другое дел :)

Comment: А где хранятся логи и все данные при использовании Crashlytics ("Логи и все данные хранятся не у вас (для некоторых критично)")?

Comment: Я имею в виду, что все логи хранятся на стороннем, не принадлежащем вам, сервере.